# How to display sql table fields in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to display the content of the fields of my "projects" table on the index page but cant seem to get it working. What am I doing wrong here?

**Model:**

```
public function prodView() {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM projects';
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index() {
         $this->load->model('main_model');
         $data ['query'] = $this->main_model->prodView(); 
         $this->load_view('/index', $data);
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
  <tr> 
    <td><?php echo $row->project_name; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What is going wrong? What happens when you run the above code?

Comment: Nothing is being outputted. @DFriend

Comment: But no error displays?

Comment: no its just blank.

Comment: Try this. Before the `foreach` line of code add this line `var_dump($query);`

Comment: Your view file name looks wrong "'/index" may be the problem

Comment: What is the name of the file that has your **View:** code in it?

Comment: its in a folder called frontend i changed that in the loadview

Answer (score 1):

**Model**

```
public function prodView() {
  $result = array();
  $this->db->select("*")->from("projects");
  $query = $this->db->get();
  if($query->num_rows() > 0){
     $result = $query->result_array();
  }
  return $result;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index() {
   $this->load->model('main_model');
   $data ['query'] = $this->main_model->prodView(); 
   $this->load->view('missio/index', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
  <tr> 
    <td><?php echo $row['project_name']; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: try to print_r($query)  or var_dump($query) check is this is empty or not

Comment: That syntax would OK be if you used `return $query->result_array();` But you did not.

Comment: also check view path $this->load_view('/index', $data); it should be $this->load_view('index', $data); or $this->load_view('FOLDER_NAME/index', $data);

Comment: @DFriend you are correct my friend but if no result then foreach will not run

Comment: var_dump($query) returned null

Comment: @Tsea then check you query, might be query is not returning any result

Comment: @Tsea var_dump($data ['query']); in controller just before loading view and place exit or die after var_dump() to check is view path is fine and results are in query

Comment: Doing that displayed the query i want on the index page but why wouldnt it work in the view

Comment: correct your view path  $this->load_view('/index', $data); it should be $this->load_view('index', $data); or $this->load_view('FOLDER_NAME/index', $data);

Comment: And/Or: In the model, just before the return statement add the line `var_dump($query);`

Comment: I did that ('FOLDER_NAME/index', $data)

Comment: Substitute `FOLDER_NAME` for the name of the folder that the view file `index.php` is in. You do have a file named 'index.php` in a sub-folder of `application/views` right?

Comment: @Tsea tell me in which folder your view file "index.php" is? is this file in application/views or application/views/your_folder_name?

Comment: application/views/folder_name

Comment: if your file is in application/views/folder_name then use in controller like this $this->load_view('folder_name/index', $data);

Comment: Thats what I have

Comment: still you are facing blank page issue ? use all of my code model controller and view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123471/discussion-between-farhan-and-tsea).